# Failed to validate a xml file (Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a)

Tags: xml, xsd

When trying to send the xml file, I get the following error:

> Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element ''CABEZERA''. One of ''{CABECERA}'' is expected.

This is the example file that I send:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ENCUESTA>
  <CABEZERA>
    <FECHA_REFERENCIA>
      <MES>07</MES>
      <ANYO>2016</ANYO>
    </FECHA_REFERENCIA>
    <DIAS_ABIERTO_MES_REFERENCIA>31</DIAS_ABIERTO_MES_REFERENCIA>
    <RAZON_SOCIAL>Alda Galicia</RAZON_SOCIAL>
    <NOMBRE_ESTABLECIMIENTO>Alda Algalia</NOMBRE_ESTABLECIMIENTO>
    <CIF_NIF>123456</CIF_NIF>
    <NUMERO_REGISTRO>11111</NUMERO_REGISTRO>
    <DIRECCION>Praciña arriba 3</DIRECCION>
    <CODIGO_POSTAL>37900</CODIGO_POSTAL>
    <LOCALIDAD>Santiago</LOCALIDAD>
    <MUNICIPIO>Santiago compostela</MUNICIPIO>
    <PROVINCIA>A coruña</PROVINCIA>
    <TELEFONO_1>923232323</TELEFONO_1>
    <TELEFONO_2>923232323</TELEFONO_2>
    <FAX_1>923212121</FAX_1>
    <FAX_2>923212121</FAX_2>
    <TIPO>H3</TIPO>
    <CATEGORIA>Hoteles</CATEGORIA>
    <HABITACIONES>23</HABITACIONES>
    <PLAZAS_DISPONIBLES_SIN_SUPLETORIAS>23</PLAZAS_DISPONIBLES_SIN_SUPLETORIAS>
    <URL>www.aldaalgalia.es</URL>
  </CABEZERA>
  <ALOJAMIENTO>
    <RESIDENCIA>
      <ID_PROVINCIA_ISLA>ES415</ID_PROVINCIA_ISLA>
      <MOVIMIENTO>
        <N_DIA>01</N_DIA>
        <ENTRADAS>0</ENTRADAS>
        <SALIDAS>0</SALIDAS>
        <PERNOCTACIONES>1</PERNOCTACIONES>
      </MOVIMIENTO>
    </RESIDENCIA>
  </ALOJAMIENTO>
  <HABITACIONES>
    <HABITACIONES_MOVIMIENTO>
      <HABITACIONES_N_DIA>01</HABITACIONES_N_DIA>
      <PLAZAS_SUPLETORIAS>0</PLAZAS_SUPLETORIAS>
      <HABITACIONES_DOBLES_USO_DOBLE>2</HABITACIONES_DOBLES_USO_DOBLE>
      <HABITACIONES_DOBLES_USO_INDIVIDUAL>0</HABITACIONES_DOBLES_USO_INDIVIDUAL>
      <HABITACIONES_OTRAS>0</HABITACIONES_OTRAS>
    </HABITACIONES_MOVIMIENTO>
  </HABITACIONES>
  <PERSONAL_OCUPADO>
    <PERSONAL_NO_REMUNERADO>0</PERSONAL_NO_REMUNERADO>
    <PERSONAL_REMUNERADO_FIJO>4</PERSONAL_REMUNERADO_FIJO>
    <PERSONAL_REMUNERADO_EVENTUAL>1</PERSONAL_REMUNERADO_EVENTUAL>
  </PERSONAL_OCUPADO>
</ENCUESTA>
```

And this xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="ENCUESTA">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Encuesta de alojamiento turístico, precios y empleo.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CABECERA">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Datos de identificacion del establecimiento. </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="FECHA_REFERENCIA">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Mes y año de referencia de los datos </xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="MES">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:length value="2"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="01"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="02"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="03"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="04"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="05"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="06"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="07"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="08"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="09"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="11"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="12"/>
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="ANYO">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:length value="4"/>
                                                    <xs:pattern value="20[0-9]{2}"/>
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="DIAS_ABIERTO_MES_REFERENCIA" type="N_DIAType"/>
                            <xs:element name="RAZON_SOCIAL">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="NOMBRE_ESTABLECIMIENTO">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="CIF_NIF">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:length value="9"/>
                                        <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9][0-9]{7}[A-Z0-9]"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="NUMERO_REGISTRO">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="DIRECCION">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="CODIGO_POSTAL">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:length value="5"/>
                                        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{5}"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="LOCALIDAD" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="MUNICIPIO">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="33"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="PROVINCIA">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="TELEFONO_1">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="9"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="13"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="TELEFONO_2" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="9"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="13"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="FAX_1" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="9"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="13"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="FAX_2" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="9"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="13"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="TIPO">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="CATEGORIA">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="HABITACIONES">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="4"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="PLAZAS_DISPONIBLES_SIN_SUPLETORIAS">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="4"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="URL" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ALOJAMIENTO">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="RESIDENCIA" id="ID_PAIS" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:choice>
                                            <xs:element name="ID_PAIS">
                                                <xs:annotation>
```

[The full xsd file here](https://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SchemaHoteles.xsd)

I can not find the problem. 
Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimally, change

```
CABEZERA
```

to

```
CABECERA
```

but you've not included enough of your XSD in the body of your question (or even securely accessible anywhere) in order to say whether you have additional issues to resolve.